# ORA-01438 value doesn't fit into defined Number(11,7) data type

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I understand the idea of Number datatype and I am acknowledged with the information from this page http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289

However it looks that I still miss something because I don't really understand why I am getting this error **ORA-01438**:

```
select cast (18000.0 as number(11,7)) from dual;
```

Results in

```
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
01438. 00000 -  "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"
*Cause:    When inserting or updating records, a numeric value was entered
           that exceeded the precision defined for the column.
*Action:   Enter a value that complies with the numeric column's precision,
           or use the MODIFY option with the ALTER TABLE command to expand
           the precision.
```

At the same time reducing scale from 7 to 6 works as a charm

```
select cast (18000.0 as number(11,6)) from dual;
```

This is happens under *'Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production'*

Can someone enlighten me on why this is happening.

Thank you, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number(11,7)` allows numbers with a **total** of 11 digits and 7 fractional digits. Which in turn means you have 11-7=4 non-fractional digits.

`18000` as five non-fractional digits which is one too many

Comment: thank you for your comment, I confused the fact that 11 is total number of digits vs non-fractional digits.